# Customize index action in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have more than 5 million records in the table (Phone).
When I click on Phone Table, It takes more then 5 min. to display a records  and on heroku it's going to crash.

I want to customize my index action. I just want to display 10,000 records and other records will be display as per the search query.

How can I do this?

I tried following but it gives me error.

> raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object

```
 controller do
    def index
        @phones = Phone.limit(10000).page(params[:page])
    end

    def permitted_params
      params.permit! 
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a pagination for index page:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Phone do
  config.per_page = 10000
end
```